# Galois group for triply tangent planes of generic algebraic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, enumerative-geometry

**Background:** The [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077313717) of Joe Harris asserts that for $d\geq 5$, the Galois group of $d(d-2)(d^2-9)/2$ bitangents of generic plane algebraic curve is the full symmetry group. I am wondering whether there are similar results for tritangent planes of generic algebraic surface, since Salmon [gave a formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/30079311.pdf) for the number $t$ of triply tangent planes with respect to the degree $n$ of the surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$: $$t=n(n-2)(n^7-4n^6+7n^5-45n^4+114n^3-111n^2+548n-960)/6.$$

**Question:** Is there any known reference for the Galois group of triply tangent planes for generic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with degree $\geq 4$?